# How to update multiple items in sharepoint list online using javascript on SP 2013 Addon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, requestexecutor

I have used the below mentioned approach to update multiple items in SharePoint 2010 list,

[How to update list items using JavaScript Object Model in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148031/how-to-update-list-items-using-javascript-object-model-in-sp-2013)

[How to update multiple items in sharepoint list online using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141987/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-sharepoint-list-online-using-javascript)

[How to update multiple items in sharepoint list online using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141987/how-to-update-multiple-items-in-sharepoint-list-online-using-javascript)

Now, i have to update multiple items in SharePoint 2013 list on my Addon. I am using the SP.RequestExecutor.js to update the single item like this,

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl +
    "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(1)?@target='" +
    hostweburl + "'",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": res.__metadata,
        Title: res.Title
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "IF-MATCH": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (onsuccess && typeof onsuccess == "function")
            onsuccess(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        if (onfailure && typeof onfailure == "function")
            onfailure(data, errorCode, errorMessage);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

How to update multiple sharepoint list items on SP 2013 Addon?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert items in batch using REST API. The following helper methods will be used.

**Helper method to insert items in batch using REST API**

```
function addItemsBatch(weburl, items, listTitle, success, fail) {

  // generate a batch boundary
  var batchGuid = generateGUID();

  // creating the body
  var batchContents = new Array();
  var changeSetId = generateGUID();

  // for each item...
  for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {

    var item = items[index];
    var endpoint = weburl
                   + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')"
                   + "/items";

    // create the changeset
    batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/http');
    batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push('POST ' + endpoint + ' HTTP/1.1');
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
    batchContents.push('');
    batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(item));
    batchContents.push('');
  }
  // END changeset to create data
  batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId + '--');


  // generate the body of the batch
  var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

  // start with a clean array
  batchContents = new Array();

  // create batch for creating items
  batchContents.push('--batch_' + batchGuid);
  batchContents.push('Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_' + changeSetId + '"');
  batchContents.push('Content-Length: ' + batchBody.length);
  batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  batchContents.push('');
  batchContents.push(batchBody);
  batchContents.push('');
  //bath end
  batchContents.push('--batch_' + batchGuid);

  batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

  // create the request endpoint 
  var endpoint = weburl + '/_api/$batch';

  // batches need a specific header
  var batchRequestHeader = {
    'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_' + batchGuid + '"'
  };

  // create request
  $.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    headers: batchRequestHeader,
    data: batchBody,
    success: function (response) {
      success();
    },
    fail: function (error) {
      fail(error);
    }
  });
}
```

**Helper method to generate random GUID for batch request**

```
function generateGUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
      var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      d = Math.floor(d / 16);
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
```

**Method to get the SP List Item Entity Name**

```
function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

**Calling method to insert items**

```
function addItems() {
    var listType = getItemTypeForListName("listTitle");
    var objItems = [
            {
                __metadata: {
                    type: listType
                },
                Title: "test1"
            },
            {
                __metadata: {
                    type: listType
                },
                Title: "test2"
            }];
    addItemsBatch(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, objItems, "listTitle", function() {
        alert('success');
    }, function(error) {
        alet('failed');
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this in my addon and i am getting the **"POST https://sitename-505e4a7d8b6f7d.sharepoint.com/jQGanttSPAddon/_api/$batch 403 (FORBIDDEN)"** error message.

Comment: It means your app do not have permissions to update. You can check the `App Permissions` by simply clicking `AppManifest` file in your solution.

Comment: I can able to update items individually.

Answer (score 0):

I will guide you to update multiple items in a SP List without hassle. I have done this many times and updated hundreds of List items in just matter of seconds. You can use **SPServices.JS** to do this. First you need to form your update string using for loop based on your requirement. Below is the sample code:

```
var itemIDArrayUpdate = [,];    
    //run some loop and prepare all data to be updated
    // I am simply showing demo for let say 10 items    
        for(var k=0; k<10; k++){
            itemIDArrayUpdate.push(["xx"+k.toString(),"yy"+k.toString(),"zz"+k.toString(),]);
        }
        // I repeat, above array is just a sample. you have write your own logic to make collection of data updates


    var update_string = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>";           
        for(var i=0; i<itemIDArrayUpdate.length; i++ )
        {
            update_string = update_string + "<Method ID='" + i + "' Cmd='Update'>" +
                "<Field Name='Field_0'>" + itemIDArrayUpdate[i][0] + "</Field>" +
                "<Field Name='Field_1'>" + itemIDArrayUpdate[i][1] + "</Field>" +    
                "<Field Name='Field_2'>" + itemIDArrayUpdate[i][2] + "</Field>" +                       
                "</Method>";

        }
        update_string = update_string + "</Batch>";        

        // apply batch to update list items

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "Update",
            listName: "your_list_name",
            webURL:"https://your_tenant/sites/your_site_name",
            updates: update_string,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
              if (xData.status == 200) {
                   alert("Updated Successfully");
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
                }                   
                }
        });
```